# Primideal, maximal ideal, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]=\{a+\sqrt{3}|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $I=(2)$ the from 2 generated ideal.
>   Is (2) a prime ideal or a maximal ideal?

Hello,

I think, that $I$ is not a prime ideal, but a maximal ideal.

Prime ideal:

$x=(\sqrt{3}+1)$, $y=(\sqrt{3}-1)$, hence $xy=(\sqrt{3}+1)(\sqrt{3}-1)=2$, but neither $x$ nor $y$ are in $(2)$. Therefor it is not a prime ideal.

Maximal ideal:

I think, that $I$ is a maximal ideal.
Consider the ideal $(2,\sqrt{3})\supset (2)$. This inclusion holds, since $\sqrt{3}\notin (2)$.
I want to show, that $(2,\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

$(2,\sqrt{3})=\{2f+\sqrt{3}g|f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]\}$

For $h\in (2,\sqrt{3})$ it is $h=2(a+\sqrt{3}b)+\sqrt{3}(c+\sqrt{3}d)=2a+3d+(2b+c)\sqrt{3}$.

For arbitrary $z=z'+z''\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, we can choose $c=0$ and $d=z''$. Hence we have to show, that for every $z'\in\mathbb{Z}$ there are $a,d\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $z'=2a+3b$, or in other words:

The function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, $(a,d)\mapsto 2a+3d$ is surjective.

Which I could not proof yet, even tho it seems quite "obvious", but I can not really find a simple argument.

Any tips?
Is there a simpler way to proof this, showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(2)$ is not a field seems out of range...

Thanks.

Comment: Every maximal ideal is prime.

Comment: That is simple enough, I guess... :) Thank you.

Comment: Why downvote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just including this as you said showing it isn't a field is out of range.

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(2)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2[\sqrt{3}]$.
Let's look at the inverse of a generic element:
$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{3}} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{3}}{a+3b}$$
For this to be integral, we need to have $a+3b\equiv 1\mod 2$.
It follows that $(1+\sqrt{3})$ isn't invertible.

To see this explicitly:
\begin{align*}
(1+\sqrt{3})(a+b\sqrt{3})  &\equiv 1\mod 2 \\
\implies a+3b+(b+a)\sqrt{3}&\equiv 1\mod 2 \\
\implies (a+b)(1+\sqrt{3})&\equiv 1\mod 2
\end{align*}
This can clearly never be true.

So, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(2)$ isn't a field, so $(2)$ isn't maximal.

Comment: But the OP already knows that $\,1+\sqrt 3\,$ isn't invertible mod 2 since it divides 2 so it is a zero-divisor mod 2.  It's not clear what is the point of your answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque It's not clear to me that _the OP_ knew this, as they said "showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(2)$ is not a field seems out of range".  The answer I gave is of a similar sort that helped me initially understand quotient rings better, so I was hoping it might help OP.